# Not able to load image to frontend - Angular

Tags: html, angular, image

I know it is annoying, because it may be asked once. But I'm struggling for days to load a simple image to my frontend. I do use Angular and as my Logo I want to upload the image "EMPLogo4.png" to the upper left corner (inside my  tag). But I do get all the time a blue box with the question mark.

When I try this with a simple html file (without angular, just html, css and js) it works fine.

I have added a screenshot of my folderstructure:

[image: Screenshot-AngularProject]

I have changed nothing in my app.component.ts file, neither the app.module.ts file.

Thank you in advance for your support.

PS: the content of the "app.component.html"

```
<img src="EMPLogo4.png" alt="emp-log">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to place it in the assets folder instead of in the root and call the image like this

```
<img src="assets/{{your image file name}}" alt="" srcset="">
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked after I moved it to the assets folder.

Answer (score 1):

If your image comes from local folder, example from `assets` folder then you should set the `src` like this:
`<img src="./assets/EMPLogo4.png" alt="emp-log">`

Since your image is within the app.component.html you can do it like this:
`<img src="./EMPLogo4.png" alt="emp-log">`

Comment: Thanks it worked after I have added it into my assets folder.